# Multiple Array Joining

Tags: php, arrays

I'm calling information from multiple tables to give me results as variables in a template. The template function is not all that relative here but getting the arrays and counts correct is the problem I seem to be struggling with. If someone could please check the code I'm certainly missing something.

The $brandFieldArray tableFields contains tableB fields information. For instance if tableB has a field called images the field in tableB will contain the path for the image but the tableFields will hold the name "image" in a field as well as type of field, length, width, quality, visible, etc. of the image.

I could easily create the fields without an array but the system can create fields that need to be added to the array without having to edit the code every time.

So I need to call the fields from tableFields and the content from tableB. The $result from tableItems is to make sure I'm getting the right content from tableB for the right item kept in tableItems.

Can you help me fix this code?

```
<?php
     switch ($requiredVar) {
         case "brand":
             $brandFieldsArray = $dbA->query("select * from tableFields where type='X' and visible=1");
             $result = $dbA->query("select bID from tableItems where iID = $x");
             if ($dbA->count($result) != null) {
                 $thisrecord = $dbA->fetch($result);
                 $bID = $thisrecord["bID"];
             } 
             else {
                 $bID = null;
             }
             $theBrandsArray = $dbA->query("select * from tableB where bID=$bID");
             $bcCount = count($theBrandsArray);
             $brandContentArray = null;
             foreach ((array) $theBrandsArray as $brandContent) {
                  $allBrandFields = "";     
                  if (is_array($brandFieldsArray)) {
                      $cc = count($brandFieldsArray);
                      foreach ($brandFieldsArray as $brField) {
                         $thisBrandField = $brField;
                         switch ($thisBrandField["fieldtype"]) {
                              case "TEXT":
                              case "TEXTAREA":
                              case "IMAGE":
                                if ($thisBrandField["fieldtype"] == "IMAGE") {
                                    if ($brandContent["brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]] == "") {
                                         $thisBrandField["content"] = $brfield["defaultimage"];
                                    } 
                                    else {
                                         $thisBrandField["content"] = $brandContent["brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]];
                                     }
                                     $thisField = generateImageVariables($brField["x"],$brField["y"]);
                                     $thisBrandField["style"] = $thisField["style"];
                                     $thisBrandField["stylefull"] = $thisField["stylefull"];
                                 } 
                                 else {
                                     $brandContent["brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]] = findCorrectLanguage($brandContent,"brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]);
                                     if (retrieveOption("convertToBR") == 1 && retrieveOption("WYSIWYGEnabled") == 0) {
                                         $thisBrandField["content"] = str_replace("\r\n","<br/>",$brandContent["brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]]);
                                     } 
                                     else {
                                          $thisBrandField["content"] = $brandContent["brandfield".$brField["fieldname"]];
                                     }
                                }
                                break;
                             }
                             $brandContent[$brField["fieldname"]] = @$thisBrandField;
                       }
                       if (is_array($allBrandFields)) {
                           $brandContent["brandfields"] = $allBrandFields;
                       } 
                       else {
                           $brandContent["brandfields"] = null;
                       }
                  }
                  $brandContentArray[] = $brandContent;
             }
             return (count($brandContentArray) == 1 ? $brandContentArray[0] : $brandContentArray);
     }
     $tpl->addVariable("brand",$brandContentArray);
     break;
?>
```

Comment: Please explain `$dbA->retrieveAllRecordsFromQuery()`. I'm not familiar with that call. I use `mysqli` myself. It uses `$query_result = $db->query()` and `if($query_result->num_rows > 0)`.

Comment: @PHPglue To be honest I can't explain it as I pulled that from the system where it was making a similar query and just reused it. What ever it takes to make this work is fine with me. mysqli queries are fine.

Comment: You start by adding `function db(){return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');}` on a separate secure `.php` page. We'll call it `connect.php`. Next you `include 'folder/connect.php';` on a the page you'll be working from. Then it's like `$db = db(); $sel = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name=value'); if($sel->num_rows > 0){while($row = $sel->fetch_object()){echo "<div>{$row->column_name}</div><div>{$row->another_column}</div>";}}else{echo 'No Rows';}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this construct with a colon at the return. Maybe you can explain. Or maybe it fixes this issue.

```
         return $brandContentArray[0] : $brandContentArray;
```

Remove this line. You must not return from inside of the case before the break. You have a following command line.

```
       // commented out: return $brandContentArray[0] : $brandContentArray;
 }
 $tpl->addVariable("brand",$brandContentArray);
 break;
```

Your description lacks important information: Which data must be returned in the array?

Comment: Data from both tableFields and tableB should be returned in the array. The data should be called based on the fieldname. The above did not fix it on its on but may be part of the solution.

Comment: returns example call in template- <#IF:brand.fieldname.type:eq:TEXT#>{brand.fieldname.content}</#IF#>           or in a loop like this     <#loop:brand.extrafields#>
<#if:brand.brandfields.content:neq:blank#>
<#if:brand.brandfields.type:eq:TEXT#>{brand.brandfields.content}</#IF#></#IF#></#IF#>

Comment: I have modified my proposal. You remove the return statement. Otherwise the template function would not be executed. If this is not the solution, then you should give more details about your template. Is there a loop inside of it?

Comment: I have made an edit to the code above and now when I call for all BRAND variables in the template I get this in return `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )`

Comment: make some var_dump statements:

`var_dump($brandFieldsArray, '$brandFieldsArray Position 1');`

Also for $theBrandsArray and some variables inside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

After further looking into the way the structure is set up with the tables I believe there is no real way to make this work in the direction I want it to. So I have decided to just make the individual calls and leave the multiple array out of it.

Thank you all for your help.